# Setting up MXUnit for multiple webroots (on a single box) such that the preferences don't need to be constantly changed for MXUnit's location

Tags: coldfusion, cfeclipse, mxunit

### Background

When we want to create a ColdFusion application (in our development environment, a separate box from my PC) we setup an IIS (internet information services) site with a physical location holding all the CFCs CFMs etc that make up our site).

As I understand it MXUnit needs to be on the webroot, as do the tests themselves so I create virtual directories to mxunit and my tests folder within IIS. I also give this site a binding (for accessing the site from my browser, I also edit my hosts file on my PC). These are then setup as ColdFusion sites using the wsconfig.exe that is provided.

In order to get MXUnit to work within Eclipse I need to set where it can find the RemoteFacade within the mxunit library is; this is relative to my binding. So I might set that it's location is:

```
http://dev19-site1/mxunit/framework/RemoteFacade.cfc
```

[image]

However; every time I have want to run my unit tests for different site I have to change these settings to

```
http://dev19-DIFFERENTSITE/mxunit/framework/RemoteFacade.cfc
```

Or else MXunit claims not to be able to find my CFCs (which makes sense as they are under a different webroot)

This gets a little irritating as I may be working on several sites at once.

### Question

Is it possible to set up MXUnit in such a way that changing the particular webroot I'm working on (but all on the same box) doesn't involve me having to constantly change the MXUnit settings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Absolutely. You can set these settings at the project, or any directory, as well.

Right click on a project or directory in Eclipse, select "MXUnit", and go from there.

For more information, click on the green "Help" icon in the MXUnit View, and you'll find full explanations.

Comment: O that is so nice, thank you. For me it was rightclick> **properties** > MXUnit